# How to raise MouseUp event of Label in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i want to raise MouseUp event of Label in MVVM.But i gives me error **"Member is not accessible or its is not recognized"** .Please Let me know where i wrong.

```
<Label Content="UserName" MouseBehaviours:MouseBehaviour.MouseUpCommand="{Binding MouseUpCommand}"   Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="40,5,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MouseUpCommand}"/>//here i am getting error
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </Label>
```

Comment: We *don't* manually raise events. Perhaps if you explain what you're *actually* trying to do, then we could suggest a better solution?

Comment: Being a beginner in mvvm.I simply wants to raise a event in mvvm.@Sheridan do you have another way

Comment: I just told you... *we don't manually raise events*, especially not when using MVVM. You want to raise an event to do something... I'm asking what you are trying to do, so that we can suggest a more appropriate course of action.

Comment: @Sheridan i want to open pop up on mouse up

Comment: So what you're *actually* trying to do is open a `Popup` control? And (ignoring the event) what is stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @Sheridan main problem is that event is not firing .Do you have any sample code or any reason why my code is not working?

Comment: At last! *main problem is that event is not firing*... Now that is *not* the same as *i want to raise MouseUp event*. The only suggestion that I have for you is for you to try using the `PreviewMouseUp` event instead.